# Using Image Source with big images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wic

I am working on an application that allows users to manipulate multiple images by using ItemsControl. I started running some tests and found that the app has problems displaying some big images - ie. it did not work with the high resolution (21600x10800), 20MB images from
http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/BlueMarble/BlueMarble_monthlies.php, though it displays the 6200x6200, 60MB Hubble telescope image from http://zebu.uoregon.edu/hudf/hudf.jpg just fine.

The original solution just specified an Image control with a Source property pointing at a file on a disk (through a binding). With the Blue Marble file - the image would just not show up. Now this could be just a bug hidden somewhere deep in the funky MVVM + XAML implementation - the visual tree displayed by Snoop goes like:

Window/Border/AdornerDecorator/ContentPresenter/Grid/Canvas/UserControl/Border/ContentPresenter/Grid/Grid/Grid/Grid/Border/Grid/ContentPresenter/UserControl/UserControl/Border/ContentPresenter/Grid/Grid/Grid/Grid/Viewbox/ContainerVisual/UserControl/Border/ContentPresenter/Grid/Grid/ItemsControl/Border/ItemsPresenter/Canvas/ContentPresenter/Grid/Grid/ContentPresenter/Image...

Now debug this! WPF can be crazy like that...

Anyway, it turned out that if I create a simple WPF application - the images load just fine. I tried finding out the root cause, but I don't want to spend weeks on it. I figured the right thing to do might be to use a converter to scale the images down - this is what I have done:

```
ImagePath = @"F:\Astronomical\world.200402.3x21600x10800.jpg";
TargetWidth = 2800;
TargetHeight = 1866;
```

and

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imageResizingConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="ImagePath"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                <Binding Path="TargetWidth"/>
                <Binding Path="TargetHeight"/>
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

and

```
public class ImageResizingConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public Image TargetImage { get; set; }
    public string SourcePath { get; set; }
    public int DecodeWidth { get; set; }
    public int DecodeHeight { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        this.SourcePath = values[0].ToString();
        this.TargetImage = (Image)values[1];
        this.DecodeWidth = (int)values[2];
        this.DecodeHeight = (int)values[3];

        return DecodeImage();
    }

    private BitmapImage DecodeImage()
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();

        bi.DecodePixelWidth = (int)DecodeWidth;
        bi.DecodePixelHeight = (int)DecodeHeight;

        bi.UriSource = new Uri(SourcePath);
        bi.EndInit();
        return bi;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, except for one "little" problem. When you just specify a file path in Image.Source - the application actually uses less memory and works faster than if you use BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth. Plus with Image.Source if you have multiple Image controls that point to the same image - they only use as much memory as if only one image was loaded. With the BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth solution - each additional Image control uses more memory and each of them uses more than when just specifying Image.Source. Perhaps WPF somehow caches these images in compressed form while if you specify the decoded dimensions - it feels like you get an uncompressed image in memory, plus it takes 6 times the time (perhaps without it the scaling is done on the GPU?), plus it feels like the original high resolution image also gets loaded and takes up space.

If I just scale the image down, save it to a temporary file and then use Image.Source to point at the file - it will probably work, but it will be pretty slow and it will require handling cleanup of the temporary file. If I could detect an image that does not get loaded properly - maybe I could only scale it down if I need to, but Image.ImageFailed never gets triggered. Maybe it has something to do with the video memory and this app just using more of it with the deep visual tree, opacity masks etc.

Actual question: How can I load big images as quickly as Image.Source option does it, without using more memory for additional copies and additional memory for the scaled down image if I only need them at a certain resolution lower than original? Also, I don't want to keep them in memory if no Image control is using them anymore.

Comment: I realize 21600x10800=233280000 pixels is a pretty big image, 890MB of uncompressed RGBA data if kept in memory as a whole chunk. Out of memory issues are usually not handled very well by code, so it is likely it can't be easily detected if WPF fails loading the image due to shortage of available RAM. It would still be nice to be able to find a workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a simple test (one image) with using DecodePixelWidth vs settings the Source on the XAML, and loading in with DecodePixelWidth took 28MB vs 178MB without the scaling down. I'm pretty sure it doesn't keep the original image in memory.

Since you said you're working with multiple images, I suspect that this is an image re-use issue. By default, WPF will cache a BitmapImage object (whether created by code or in XAML). It looks at the SourceUri as well as the DecodePixelWidth and DecodePixelHeight to find a match. If your TargetWidth and TargetHeight are changing, it would mean that WPF can't re-use its image cache; something that would not be a problem if you set the source without any extra options.

Comment: How do you check memory consumption (I just check private working set in task manager)? Which version of WPF (I think I use 3.51, but don't have access to the machine now).

Comment: I'm checking memory in the same way. I'm using 3.5 SP1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with same problem and looks like when **BitmapImage** property **CreateOptions** = set to **BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile** its working faster.

Other thing that we can create cache for our BitmapImages that used offten. I know that WPF should do this automatically but i thinks it will works faster. If somebody will try to measure loading time just write comments:)